# How to get the IETF RFC7919 recommended DH parameter file on board of a router (for Nginx)?

Tags: nginx, ssl, openwrt

According to [Mozilla server side TLS should use](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#DHE_handshake_and_dhparam) the pre-defined DH groups `ffdhe2048`, `ffdhe3072` or `ffdhe4096` recommended by the IETF in [RFC 7919](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7919).

My router is running Nginx (and Linux), thus `ssl_dhparam` should be set.

#### No gnutls package

However the router its (Entware-NG) package management system lacks a `gnutls` package as suggested to install by [Adam the Sysadmin](https://adamthesysadmin.com/2017/05/export-rfc7919-dhparams-in-pem-format/).

#### DH parameters file

What is a simple way to get the DH Parameters file on board of a router running the padavan (openwrt derived) distribution via SSH?

Comment: Have a look at https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some copy and pastable shell one liners for the 2048 (medium) and 3072 (high) DH parameters.

#### Ffdhe2048 (recommended for compatibility)

```
$ { echo -----BEGIN\ DH\ PARAMETERS-----; echo MIIBDAKCAQEA//////////+t+FRYortKmq/cViAnPTzx2LnFg84tNpWp4TZBFGQz; echo +8yTnc4kmz75fS/jY2MMddj2gbICrsRhetPfHtXV/WVhJDP1H18GbtCFY2VVPe0a;echo 87VXE15/V8k1mE8McODmi3fipona8+/och3xWKE2rec1MKzKT0g6eXq8CrGCsyT7; echo YdEIqUuyyOP7uWrat2DX9GgdT0Kj3jlN9K5W7edjcrsZCwenyO4KbXCeAvzhzffi; echo 7MA0BM0oNC9hkXL+nOmFg/+OTxIy7vKBg8P+OxtMb61zO7X8vC7CIAXFjvGDfRaD; echo ssbzSibBsu/6iGtCOGEoXJf//////////wIBAgICAQA=; echo -----END\ DH\ PARAMETERS-----;  } > /opt/etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam_2048.pem && chmod 600 /opt/etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam_2048.pem
```

In nginx.conf, when it's not there, add:

```
ssl_dhparam          ssl/dhparam_2048.pem;
```

#### Or use ffdhe3072

```
$ { echo -----BEGIN\ DH\ PARAMETERS-----; echo MIIBjAKCAYEA//////////+t+FRYortKmq/cViAnPTzx2LnFg84tNpWp4TZBFGQz; echo +8yTnc4kmz75fS/jY2MMddj2gbICrsRhetPfHtXV/WVhJDP1H18GbtCFY2VVPe0a; echo 87VXE15/V8k1mE8McODmi3fipona8+/och3xWKE2rec1MKzKT0g6eXq8CrGCsyT7; echo YdEIqUuyyOP7uWrat2DX9GgdT0Kj3jlN9K5W7edjcrsZCwenyO4KbXCeAvzhzffi; echo 7MA0BM0oNC9hkXL+nOmFg/+OTxIy7vKBg8P+OxtMb61zO7X8vC7CIAXFjvGDfRaD; echo ssbzSibBsu/6iGtCOGEfz9zeNVs7ZRkDW7w09N75nAI4YbRvydbmyQd62R0mkff3; echo 7lmMsPrBhtkcrv4TCYUTknC0EwyTvEN5RPT9RFLi103TZPLiHnH1S/9croKrnJ32; echo nuhtK8UiNjoNq8Uhl5sN6todv5pC1cRITgq80Gv6U93vPBsg7j/VnXwl5B0rZsYu; echo N///////////AgECAgIBFA==; echo -----END\ DH\ PARAMETERS-----;  } > /opt/etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam_3072.pem && chmod 600 /opt/etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam_3072.pem
```

In nginx.conf, when it's not there, add:

```
ssl_dhparam          ssl/dhparam_3072.pem;
```

Comment: Should you be posting your files, instead of generating them?

Comment: Mozilla has these, and the third one, which is `ffdhe4096`, on their website, at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Pre-defined_DHE_groups

Comment: These are public constants (namely 2^2048 − 2^1984 + ([2^1918 · e] + 560316) · 2^64 − 1 and 2^3072 − 2^3008 + ([2^2942 · e] + 2625351) · 2^64 − 1, respectively), so there’s no need to restrict them to mode 600.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg What is your suggestion for mode, instead of `600`?